# Creating Point Grid over selected polygon using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, point, grids-graticules

I am trying to create an equally spaced grid of points. But these points must only be on land.

I was using the polygon overlay of countries to see if I can use that as a mask.

I have also tried using graticule to see if its possible to point points in a grid from this.

Documentation is very lacking on this. I can see how to do this using pointGrid() in OL2 but obviously being outdated this isn't going to be practical.

Can anyone give any pointers on how to over come this or where to start importing the pointGrid() function to solve the problem.